# How to represent the following in first order logic or propositional logic?

Tags: first-order-logic

Marisa, John and Bob attend at least one student club in their university. Their university  has  two  student  clubs: a  cinema club  and  a literatur eclub.  No  student  in  the literature club likes cola and all students in the cinema club like popcorn. Marisa likes popcorn, but she does not like cola. John likes both popcorn and cola. Bob dislikes whatever John likes.

**UPDATED**

Here is what I did so far:

$\forall x(University(x) \land HasClub(x,cinema) \land HasClub(x,literature))$

$\forall x( (Member(literature,x) \land Student(x)) \rightarrow \neg Likes(x,cola) )$

$\forall x((Student(x) \land Member(cinema,x)) \rightarrow Likes(x,popcorn) )$

$Likes(marisa,popcorn) \land \neg Likes(marisa,cola)$

$Likes(john,popcorn) \land Likes (john,cola)$

$\forall x( Likes(john,x) \rightarrow \neg Likes(bob,x))$

Comment: Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: Let me update the question with what I did so far.

Comment: @PatrickStevens can you check I updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some superficial edits to your post, using proper logical symbols, adding a few missing parentheses, making sure all predicates start with capital letters, and all objects with small letters. I also switched the order of the objects inside the $Likes(x,y)$ predicate, so that $Likes(x,y)$ means'that $x$ likes $y$, rather than $y$ likes $x$ ... I think the former reads a lot more naturally.

As far as content goes: the only comment I have is with regard to the first sentence, which says that *every* university has a literature and cinema club, which is not something we know given the English sentences: all we know is that the university that Marisa, John, and Bob attend has those two clubs. So, you may want to use a constant (say, $c$) for that university as well, in which case we simply get:

$HasClub(c,literature) \land HasClub(c,cinema)$

Another option is to not use a constant for the university, but to use a 'Is a university' predicate ... this will also force us to specify that this unievrsity is the one Bob, John, and Marise attend, which I think is a good idea. So:

$\exists x (University(x) \land Attend(john,x) \land Attend (marisa,x) \land Attend(bob,x) \land HasClub(x,literature) \land HasClub(x,cinema))$

Otherwise, everything seems fine!